# Version 4.7.3: TCPDF package seems to be missing

Tags: wordpress, upgrade, pdf

I recently upgraded to vesion 4.7.3 (I'm running under Wordpress), and for some reason the TCPDF package was missing!

This led to the error: "Warning: opendir(/nhldata/631/106631/data/web/predigerforum/htdocs/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm//packages/tcpdf/fonts/): failed to open dir: No such file or directory in /nhldata/631/106631/data/web/predigerforum/htdocs/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/tecnickcom/tcpdf/tcpdf.php on line 4148
TCPDF ERROR: Could not include font definition file: helvetica"

...when trying to create labels. I copied the directory "tcpdf" from the previous version into the packages directory and it seems to be OK now.

Perhaps there is a slip up in V 4.7.3, because I did nothing more than the normal upgrade process.

Comment: Still missing in 4.7.7 ;-(  As before, I simply did a standard upgrade.

Comment: I can confirm the same issue is in 4.6.16 version for Drupal. The 4.6.12 had those files so copying the civicrm/packages/tdpdf/ folder (from an older version of CiviCRM or a backup before the upgrade) to the newly upgraded CiviCRM solves the problem

Comment: Still missing in 4.7.8 ;-( As before, I simply did a standard upgrade.

Comment: Have opened an issue @ [CRM-18755: TCPDF uses incorrect font path after upgrade](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-18755). If your site is affected by this, maybe hit us up on https://chat.civicrm.org/ so we can debug a bit better :)

Comment: Please see comment below. Cheers, David

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In 4.7.3 the TCPDF package was moved to civicrm/vendor/tecnickcom  from civicrm//packages/tcpdf.

I just tested on a WP 4.5.2 and CiviCRM 4.7.8 install and was able to create mailing labels.

Can you give us the steps to reproduce?  This may be a bug that needs an issue filed at https://issues.civicrm.org

One additional thought - try and empty the caches in WP the url is `https://yourdomain.org/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/admin/setting/updateConfigBackend&reset=1`

Comment: I realised when I saw this that I had added a variable setting in the past to ensure that CiviCRM could find the font files: this correction is of course now wrong. Obviously, I had missed the change in package positioning - was this ever announced?

Comment: I realised when I saw this that I had added a change in the past to ensure that CiviCRM could find the font files: this correction is of course now wrong. Obviously, I missed the package positioning change in 4.7.3: was this ever announced? If I remove that change, then things work correctly again for me. I had marked my change: "Force TCPDF to work when open basedir is enforced - see CiviCRM Jira CRM-14345", and I had to override 'K_PATH_MAIN' with '$civicrm_root . '/packages/tcpdf/' and 'K_PATH_IMAGES' with '$civicrm_root . '/packages/tcpdf/include/'. So please link new Jira with CRM-14345