# TCPDF package is missing in the standard distribution

Tags: wordpress, upgrade, pdf

Since version 4.7.3 the files for the TCPDF package are missing. Please could someone in the know arrange to update the standard distribution! Thanks

See: [Version 4.7.3: TCPDF package seems to be missing](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/10656/version-4-7-3-tcpdf-package-seems-to-be-missing)

Comment: Thanks for reporting David - yes this looks like CiviCRM has cached the font path and doesn't handle the relocation. Have opened an issue @ [CRM-18755: TCPDF uses incorrect font path after upgrade](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-18755). Closing this question as a duplicate of your earlier post - thanks for persisting in raising this :)

Comment: Thanks - I only duplicated because my previous question had an explicit version number in it and had seemed to have gone off the radar...

Comment: I've marked the other issue as a correct answer. Thanks again